# Suppose $f$ is a differentiable function and its inverse function $f^{-1}$ is also differentiable.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $$f(4)=5 ~\mbox{and}~ f'(4)=2/3, ~\mbox{find}~ (f^{-1})(5). (f^{-1})'(5) = $$

So I'm interpreting this to mean that based on what I'm given, find what the derivative would have to be to raise $f(x)$ to $5$. Then find what the rate of change would be in raising $x$ from $5$ to $6$.

Comment: Do you know what $f^{-1}(5)$ is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse function theorem states that if you have a differentiable function who's derivative is non-zero,  then locally the inverse function exists and is differentiable. For notational ease, call $g(x)$ the inverse function of f,  then you get $g'(x)=\frac 1 {f'(g(x))}$.

So, plugging in 5,  you get 
$g'(5)=\frac 1 {f'(g(5))}=\frac 1 {f'(4)}=\frac 1 {\frac 2 3}=\frac 3 2$